# interfaces stopped working

Tags: centos, interface

I have a cisco machine with centos 6.5 installed on it and all of a sudden my network interfaces stopped working. When trying to restart the network service with /etc/init.d/network restart I got the error:

```
** (process:6538): WARNING **: _nm_object_get_property: Error getting 'State' for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4: (19) Method "Get" with signature "ss" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist
```

Regarding the above error, I searched through thick and thin and couldn't find a solution.

I restarted the server but still nothing. Even when using ethtool ethx, I get "Cannot get device settings:Operation not permitted...."

I'm hoping that I don't need to re-install the server. Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: `I have a cisco machine` - What exactly is this cisco machine that you're referring to?

Comment: What does `ifconfig -a` output?